# Phonegap - ReferenceError: Can't find variable when calling db.transaction

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an iPhone application using [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) & [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). The application is using WebSQL for local storage via the [Phonegap storage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).

I have been developing and testing in Chrome, and everything is working fine, but when testing in Safari I am getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: loadBookingItems
```

This happens in my pageinit function:

```
  $(document).on('pageinit', '#booking_page',  function(){              
     db.transaction(loadBookingItems);
  });
```

The *loadBookingItems* function is located in a .js file:

```
function loadBookingItems(tx){
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM booking", [], loadBookingItemsSuccess, loadBookingItemsFail);
}
```

The file is getting loaded, and like I said, it is working in Chrome. jQuery is definitely getting loaded.

*db* is being defined as a global variable:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("mydb", "1.0", "mydb", 200000);
```

Any ideas as to what the problem is, and why it is only happening in safari?

Comment: Can you provide more code? How is `loadBookingItems` being initialized in the other file?

Comment: Hey @IngoBürk :) I updated my question with the loadBookingItems function

Comment: As of now I share your confusion; I don't see anything wrong. Can you try and check `console.log(loadBookingItems);` in your pageinit event? If this gives `undefined`, do the same somewhere else in the code -- just to see if the variable does exist or not.

Comment: Thanks Ingo. When I put console.log(loadBookingItems); as the first thing in my <script> it logs the function (as it appears in the .js file). When I put it in the pageinit() it returns this same error (can't find variable)

Comment: How do you load the two js files? What happens if you (just for testing) switch from `pageinit` to `pageshow`?

Comment: It works now when using pageshow. Thanks Ingo. Please write it as an answer so I can mark as accepted. Also, what is the difference between pageshow() and pageinit()?

Comment: It's not solved yet, `pageinit` and `pageshow` are different events. The latter one is called everytime the page is shown, the first one only when it's being initialized. You should decide which event you are actually looking for, just from what I gather `pageshow` might be what you were looking for anyway?

Comment: `pageshow()` is more in line with what I want (the db.transaction does need to be executed every time the page is loaded). I don't understand why it was giving this particular error though, that usually happens if jQuery is not being loaded?

Comment: To be honest, I would expect it to work with `pageinit` too, and I don't have an explanation why it doesn't. If you want it to be executed everytime, `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow` are the events you should use anyway, though. I guess it has to do with when/how you're loading your js files.

Comment: Thanks anyway Ingo, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow` are more suitable events than `pageinit`if you want to update the loaded items everytime the page is being shown -- and apparently it's working fine there.